# How to use appium scrollto function to scroll to an element using its ID

Tags: appium, scrollto

I want to scroll to an element by its ID using appium scrollto.

How do I do that? Currently only text can be entered in the `scrollto` function.

Answer (score -1):

I am using some Javascript code to achieve this. Maybe this can also help you. But again each solution is specific to the problem (i.e. App). Now at the same I don't know how you got an upvote for your question as it shows zero research and gives no information.

```
No mention of Android OS or iOS, 
No mention of application type - Hybrid, Native, etc.
No mention of what you have achieved until now with scrollto any snippet etc.
```

Having said that I am going to share some of the Javascript that I am using in my code. Again this is specific to my app. Maybe you require a more tailored solution for your problem.

```
public class Scroll extends Driver{

    public static void scrolldown(){
        //Scroll JS
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) Ad ;
        HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
        scrollObject.put("direction", "down");
        js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);
    }

    public static void scrollup(){
        //Scroll JS
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) Ad ;
        HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
        scrollObject.put("direction", "up");
        js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);
    }
}
```